# coding base on UML diagram c++

Tags: c++, uml

I have a Line class UML diagram which shows the following details

```
 - pOne: Point
 - pTwo: Point
 + Line (ptOne: Point, ptTwo: Point)
 + getPOne () : Point
 + getPTwo () : Point
 + setPOne (pOne: Point) 
 + setPTwo (pTwo: Point)
```

)

this is what I have done according to my interpretation of the UML diagram

Line.h

```
#ifndef __testing__Line__
#define __testing__Line__
#include <iostream>
#include "Point"

class Line  {

private:
   //pOne and pTwo are objects of Point 
   Point pOne;
   Point pTwo;

public:

    Line() {

    };//default Constructor

    // constructor of class Line to store objects of Point(pOne,pTwo)
    Line (Point pOne,Point pTwo);

    // get method for objects of Point(pOne,pTwo)
    Point getPOne();
    Point getPTwo();

    // set method for objects of a(one,two)
    void setPOne (Point pOne);
    void setPTwo (Point pTwo);

};
#endif /* defined(__testing__Line__) */
```

Line.cpp

```
#include "Line.h"

Line::Line (Point pOne, Point pTwo)  {
    setPOne(pOne);
    setPTwo(pTwo);
}

Point Line::getPOne()    {
    return pOne;
}

Point Line::getPTwo()    {
    return pTwo;
}

Line::setPOne (Point pOne)   {
     this-> pOne = pOne;
}

Line::setATwo (Point pTwo)   {
     this->pTwo = pTwo;
}
```

and in main cpp I tried to call the function getPOne()

main.cpp

```
#include "Point"
#include "Line"

int main() {
    Line outputMethod;
    //Invalid operands to binary expression
    std::cout << outputMethod.getPOne() << std::endl;
}
```

How should I call getPOne() from Line class given in the above situation?

---

operator overloading

```
//overload << operator
friend std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Point&)
{
  return os;
}
```

Comment: `std::cout << outputMethod.getPOne() << std::endl;`

Comment: sorry i missed out on the (). but I still getting the error

Comment: Do you have `operator<<` defined for Point?

Comment: nope and I don't know what is that. sorry mind explaining what does the operator << does?

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 issues with your implementation:

1. You shouldn't derive your `Line` class from `Point` - it's wrong semantically (`Line` isn't a kind of `Point`) and according to the UML description as well.
2. You need to define a proprietary operator `<<` for your `Point` class in order to use it with `cout`. If you don't do that, the compiler doesn't know how to print your data (it's your proprietary defined data, after all).

Comment: proprietary operator << as in something like what is shown in my edited codes?

Comment: Not really, the implementation has to match your `Point` class. Consider the `operator <<` as a function `print` for `Point`. It's semantically equivalent in your case. Now think how would you write the `print` function and do the same for `operator <<`. And better yet, read the operator overloading chapter in any C++ book.

Comment: alright guess I will have to spend some time to read about it. thanks anyway